# c programming malloc question

Tags: c, malloc

Just got query regarding c malloc() function. I am read()ing x number of bytes from a file to get lenght of filename, like ' read(file, &namelen, sizeof(unsigned char)); ' .

The variable namelen is a type unsigned char and was written into file as that type (1 byte). Now namelen has the lenght of filename ie namelen=8 if file name was 'data.txt', plus extra /0 at end, that working fine.

Now I have a structure recording file info, ie filename, filelenght, content size etc.

```
   struct fileinfo
        {
              char *name;
              ...... other variable like size etc

        };
struct fileinfo *files;
```

Question: I want to make that files.name variable the size of namelen ie 8 so I can successfully write the filename into it, like ' files[i].name = malloc(namelen) '

However, I dont want it to be malloc(sizeof(namelen)) as that would make it file.name[1] as the size of its type unsigned char. I want it to be the value thats stored inside variable &namelen ie 8 so file.name[8] so data.txt can be read() from file as 8 bytes and written straight into file.name[8?

Is there a way to do this my current code is this and returns 4 not 8

```
files[i].name = malloc(namelen);
//strlen(files[i].name) - returns 4

//perhaps something like
malloc(sizeof(&namelen)) but does not work
```

Thanks for any suggestions

Have tried suggested suggestions guys, but I now get a segmentation fault error using:

```
printf("\nsizeofnamelen=%x\n",namelen); //gives 8 for data.txt
files[i].name = malloc(namelen + 1);
read(file, &files[i].name, namelen);
int len=strlen(files[i].name); printf("\nnamelen=%d",len);
printf("\nname=%s\n",files[i].name);
```

When I try to open() file with that files[i].name variable it wont open so the data does not appear to be getting written inside the read() &files[i].name and strlen() causes segemntation error as well as trying to print the filename

Comment: Updated my answer regarding your segmentation fault.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. a string is `strlen(name) + 1` bytes long (because of the terminating `\0`).
2. if `namelen = strlen("data.txt")` (i.e. 8) then you must allocate `files[i].name = malloc(namelen + 1)`
3. any memory you allocate using `malloc()` is *undefined*. You *cannot* perform `strlen()` on memory you just allocated - you must set the memory you've allocated first
4. only after you *allocate* the memory can you *use* the memory, i.e. `strncpy( files[i].name, "data.txt", namelen + 1 )` and only *then* can you `strlen( files[i].name )`

Comment: Please read above question been edited about segmentation fault error

Comment: After the `read()` please add: `files[i].name[namelen] = '\0';` - you will get a segfault when issuing `strlen()` on memory that doesn't have a '\0' (because `strlen` only stops counting when it reaches a `\0`).

Comment: Also, change `read( file, files[i].name, namelen )` - you're trying to write on top of a pointer when you should be writing to the memory the pointer points to (I think you need to re-read K&R on pointers and the `&` operator).

Answer (score 2):

The code you have is (almost) the correct way to allocate the memory, you need to include space for the trailing NULL byte:

```
files[i].name = malloc(namelen + 1);
```

Note that at this point the string is not initialized, so `strlen(files[i].name)` will either return a random number of crash. You can use `memset()` to zero the memory and then  `strlen(files[i].name)` will return 0. If you read the data from the file, `strlen(files[i].name)` will return 8.

Comment: Please read above question been edited about segmentation fault error I get as result

Comment: Two problems 1) Read into `files[i].name`, not `&files[i].name` 2) you are missing the trailing NULL byte in the string --`files[i].name[namelen] = 0;` should fix that.

Answer (score 1):

malloc returns uninitialized memory, thus the result of

```
strlen(files[i].name)
```

directly after

```
files[i].name = malloc(namelen);
```

is undefined.

And `strlen` counts the characters until the first '\0' character in a memory block - it does not return the memory block size allocated by a former `malloc` call.

**Regarding question update:**

A `read` does not terminate the destination with a '\0' character, and this is why you get a segmentation fault.

Inserting a

```
files[i].name[namelen] = '\0';
```

properly terminates the C-string and should fix this issue.

Alternatively you could use `calloc` instead of malloc.

Answer (score 1):

If the filename won't change, you can be a bit efficient and allocate both the structure and the space for the filename in the same `malloc()`:

```
struct fileinfo *files = malloc(sizeof *files + namelen + 1);
files->name = (char *) (files + 1);
```

This allocates a single block of memory which is large enough for the `struct fileinfo` (i.e. `sizeof *files` bytes) and the '\0'-terminated filename (`namelen + 1`). The second line make the `name` member of the struct point at the first byte after the struct itself.

You can then go ahead and write the filename into `files->name` by e.g. loading it with another call to `read()`.

You can free the entire structure, including the filename, with a single call to `free(files)` when you're done with it.

Comment: Hm, interesting trick, but I suspect that you'd need identical usage patterns for *all* allocations, or a flag in the structure, indicating if it is a "free all" or "free strings, then free base" (probably from a custom wrapper around free).

Answer (score 0):

Did you allocate space for the files?
Currently, it is struct fileinfo * files;

Assuming you did something like this:
files = malloc(sizeof(struct fileinfo) * num_files);

```
printf("\nsizeofnamelen=%x\n",namelen); //gives 8 for data.txt
files[i].name = malloc(namelen + 1);
read(file, &files[i].name, namelen);
files[i].name[namelen] = '\0'; // NUL-terminate the string.
int len=strlen(files[i].name); printf("\nnamelen=%d",len);
printf("\nname=%s\n",files[i].name);
```

If you don't NUL-terminate the string (file[i].name) then you will keep reading random stuff and possibly segfault.

Answer (score 0):

```
read(file, &files[i].name, namelen);
```

should be

```
read(file, files[i].name, namelen);
```

Because files[i].name stores the address of the allocated buffer.  Since the prototype for read is void* your compiler might be letting you get away with passing a char** rather than reporting an error.

Also as maxschlepzig said, don't forget to add a \0 to the end of the buffer.